# Ag-grid external filter in angular 2, filter presents but grid not updating

Tags: ag-grid

app.component.html

```
<div class="inlineBlock">
    <select [(ngModel)]="portId" id="portDropdownMenu" (change)="externalFilterChanged()">
        <option *ngFor="#portId of portIds">{{portId}}</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <ag-grid-ng2 #agGrid
                 [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
                 [columnDefs]="myColumnDefs"
                 [rowData]="myRowData"
                 enableColResize
                 rowSelection="multiple"
                 enableSorting
                 enableFilter
                 [isExternalFilterPresent]="isExternalFilterPresent"
                 [doesExternalFilterPass]="doesExternalFilterPass"
                 rowHeight="30"
                 headerHeight="40"
                 enableRangeSelection
                 suppressContextMenu
                 suppressMenuColumnPanel
                 rowGroupPanelShow="always"
                 rememberGroupStateWhenNextData
                 groupDefaultExpanded="-1"
                 groupHideGroupColumns
                 groupUseEntireRow
                 (modelUpdated)="onModelUpdated()"
                 (filterChanged)="onFilterChanged()">
    </ag-grid-ng2>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
public isExternalFilterPresent() {
        return this.portType != "All Ports";
}

public doesExternalFilterPass(node) {
    switch (this.portType) {
        case "1": return node.data.Port === "1";
        case "2": return node.data.Port === "2";
        case "3": return node.data.Port === "3";
        default: return true;
    }

}

public externalFilterChanged() {
    var newValue = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("portDropdownMenu")).value
    this.portType = newValue;
    this.gridOptions.api.onFilterChanged();
}

public onFilterChanged() {
    if (this.gridOptions.api.isAnyFilterPresent()) {
        this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(this.gridOptions.rowData);
        this.gridOptions.api.refreshView();
    }
    console.log("filter changed ...");
}
```

By console.log(this.gridOption.isAnyFilterPresented()), I notice the filter does exist when dropdown menu is updated. However, the grid is not updating according to external filter.

I am pretty sure "isExternalFilterPresent()" and "doesExternalFilterPass(node)" run through and provides the correct return value. My understanding is that ag-grid will take care of the rest but it is not doing it. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update on this issue:

The problem for me is the scope in angular 2 variables. `this.portType` is undefined in `isExternalFilterPresent()` and `doesExternalFilterPass(node)` even I initialized properly in the constructor. My fix is to retrieve portType from HTML each time those two functions are called.

It is not a nice fix, hopefully, someone could come up with something better. And if anyone could explain why the `portType` variable was undefined?

Answer (score 12):

there is a solution to this issue.

declare the two functions: isExternalFilterPresent,doesExternalFilterPass in type script,

get an instance of the gridOptions,

```
  private gridOptions:GridOptions;
```

and in the constructor:

```
  this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{};
```

then

```
  this.gridOptions.isExternalFilterPresent  =  this.isExternalFilterPresent.bind(this);
  this.gridOptions.doesExternalFilterPass = this.doesExternalFilterPass.bind(this);
```

now, you will be able to access the component's variables inside those functions:

```
   this.myVariable
```

full description the problem+solution:
https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid-ng2/issues/121

Comment: this should be the accepted answer; re-wiring the context is a better solution than scouring the DOM for the data

Answer (score 2):

`doesExternalFilterPass` and `isExternalFilterPresent` are an arrow function so `this` has no meaning inside these functions. Below is how they should be used -

```
/**
   * This property is an arrow function, which binds `this` to the Angular Component.
   * It's necessary otherwise `this` is undefined inside the function because
   * it's not called as a method of the class by the Datagrid.
   * It's called as `doesExternalFilterPass(node)` and not as `component.doesExternalFilterPass(node)`
   */
  doesExternalFilterPass = (node: RowNode): boolean => {
    return node.data.currency >= this.currencyFilter;
  }
```

Source - https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid-angular/issues/121

Comment: This is great! Good fix and nice explanation of fundamentals