# ag-grid external filter using angular2

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I want to implement external filtering on ag-grid with angular2.

The ag-grid [example on github](https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid-ng2-example/tree/master/app) doesn't seem to implement external filters and [a similar question has not been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37957310/ag-grid-external-filter-in-angular-2-filter-presents-but-grid-not-updating). Is there a way of implementing external filters in ag-grid with angular2?

I have the following:

**Template:**

```
<input (keyup)="updateFilters($event)" name="filterAgreementNumber" #filterAgreementNumber/>

<ag-grid-ng2 #agGrid
         style="width: 100%;"
         [style.height.px]="height"
         class="ag-fresh"
         [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
         [rowData]="promises"
         (window:resize)="onResize($event)">
```

**Component:**

```
export class PromisesListComponent {
    private gridOptions: GridOptions;
    private promises: Promise[];
    filterAgreementNumber = '';

    constructor(private promisesService: PromisesService) {
        this.gridOptions = {
            rowData: this.promises,
            columnDefs: this.createColumnDefs(),
            enableColResize: true,
            enableSorting: true,
            enableFilter: true,
            isExternalFilterPresent: this.externalFilterPresent,
            doesExternalFilterPass: this.externalFilterPass,            
    }

    updateFilters(event: any) {
        this.filterAgreementNumber = event.target.value; //correctly assigns property
        this.gridOptions.api.onFilterChanged();
    }

    externalFilterPass(node: any) {
        console.log(this.getFilterAgreementNumber); //undefined
        if (this.filterAgreementNumber && this.filterAgreementNumber.length > 0)
            if (node.data.AgreementCode.indexOf(this.filterAgreementNumber) === -1)
            return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that `this` in the `externalFilterPass` refers to the ag-grid node and I have no way of accessing the class property.

Comment: If you consider an alternative, PrimeNG DataTable has external filter feature. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatablefilter

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In the constructor, instead of

```
this.gridOptions = {
   ...
   isExternalFilterPresent: this.externalFilterPresent,
   doesExternalFilterPass: this.externalFilterPass
}
```

try

```
this.gridOptions = {
   ...
   isExternalFilterPresent: this.externalFilterPresent.bind(this),
   doesExternalFilterPass: this.externalFilterPass.bind(this)
}
```

Now the component context will be accessible from within the ag-grid methods, and `this` will be what you expected it to be.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41965934/6432429

Answer (score 0):

did you add @Injectable() above your class?

also:
rewrite your gridOptions function like so:

```
        ..., doesExternalFilterPass: (node) => { return this.doesExternalFilterPass(this, node); }, ...
```

and use in your class:

```
private doesExternalFilterPass(gcs, node): boolean {
    if (<GridRowStatus>gcs.gridActionsService.filter) {
        console.log(gcs.gridActionsService.filter);
        console.log(node.data);
        return gcs.rowStatusService.contains(node.data, [gcs.gridActionsService.filter]);
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```