# Why ag-Grid isExternalFilterPresent.bind(this) not working?

Tags: angular, datagrid, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have following code to support angular data grid external filter

```
gridOptions: GridOptions;
filter = { isHorizontal : false, isVertical: false };

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{ editType: 'fullRow' };
    this.gridOptions.isExternalFilterPresent = this.isExternalFilterPresent.bind(this);
    this.gridOptions.doesExternalFilterPass = this.doesExternalFilterPass.bind(this);
}


isExternalFilterPresent(): boolean {
    return this.filter.isHorizontal && this.filter.isVertical;
}
```

When refresh the page, there is error from `isExternalFilterPresent()`:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isHorizontal')
```

So binding of `this` doesn't work, however I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37957310/ag-grid-external-filter-in-angular-2-filter-presents-but-grid-not-updating) post did the exactly the same, not sure where went wrong

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an angular error, try with the following snippet:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.gridOptions = {
      editType:'fullRow',
      isExternalFilterPresent: this.isExternalFilterPresent.bind(this),
      doesExternalFilterPass: this.doesExternalFilterPass.bind(this),
    };
}
```

Comment: thank you for the advice. I tried but got same error

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue in a codesandox/plunkr?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and spent hours trying to figure it out. It turned out I had

```
this.gridOptions = {
    editType:'fullRow',
    isExternalFilterPresent: this.isExternalFilterPresent.bind(this),
    doesExternalFilterPass: this.doesExternalFilterPass.bind(this),
};
```

in the component.ts, but I also had

```
<ag-grid
    [isExternalFilterPresent]="isExternalFilterPresent"
    [doesExternalFilterPass]="doesExternalFilterPass">
```

in the html file which overrode `this.gridOptions`.

After I removed the properties from html file it started working as expected. My `doesExternalFilterPass()` sees `this` as the component now.